# Yii array helper selecting already set value from database

Tags: javascript, php, yii, yii2, array-map

Am using array helpers if data exists i want to select the value...here product category master id is a foreign key in product master table.
A modal gets called on edit button and it uses the same modal as create button
but the fields are populated using hidden input field.

I want to select the already set value from the database.

```
                       $("#productmaster-product_category_master_id").val(data.product_category_master_id);
```

The above code is not working.

```
<?= $product_form->field($form_product_model, 'product_category_master_id')->dropDownList(

                                ArrayHelper::map(ProductCategoryMaster::find()->all(),'id','category'),['prompt'=>'','class'=>'form-control select2','style' => 'width:100%;height:80% !important']

                            );?>



function editProduct(id) {
    console.log(id);
    $.ajax
    ({
        type:"GET",
        url: "<?= Yii::getAlias('@web')?>/product-category-master/product?id="+id,
        cache: false,
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);

            $('#sourceproduct').click();
                       $("#newid").val(data.id);

                       $("#productmaster-product_category_master_id").val(data.product_category_master_id);
                                    //document.getElementById("editbutton").showModal();
                        //var myArr = JSON.parse(data);

            return false;
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: what's the question .. you have error ..  ?  show the error message ..     otherwise explain your need ..   .

Comment: no theres no error its just isnt selecting value, am using select2

Comment: Found the solution i just had to put  $('#productmaster-product_category_master_id').val(data.product_category_master_id).trigger('change'); instead of  $('#productmaster-product_category_master_id').val(data.product_category_master_id);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution i just had to put

```
$('#productmaster-product_category_master_id').val(data.product_category_master_id).trigger('change');
```

instead of

```
$('#productmaster-product_category_master_id').val(data.product_category_master_id);
```